# A debug utility to print or extract intermediate data from a program

Tags: debugging

Is there a way to print variables using their names, or to extract the corresponding information for later analysis ?

Comment: It would be nice to know why someone downvoted this. Self-answered questions are not frowned upon; in fact, they are explicitly encouraged.

Comment: I wrote the answer to this question before in a related question I asked (Is it possible to print expressions in reverse order?). But given what I read, I thought it deserves to be in a proper question/answer format. Anyway I'm not competing for rep, just want to share this utility that I think is very useful.

Comment: I think it's good to note here that the built-in debugger can show the names and values of variables.

Comment: Yes but sometimes you want to have the variables available for a step by step debugging in the frontend, and this utility is useful for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This version of [ShowIt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168036/884752) first shown by Leonid Shifrin is particularly useful, it can be used in conjunction with the function `ReapTags[]` defined below also.

It now uses the `LetL[]` function also from Leonid defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/66) (in order to avoid a nested With for printedExpr).

I've incorporated the answer of Szabolcs to the question [Is it possible to Print expressions in reverse order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4129/66), the answer of Mr. Wizard to the question [Delete contexts from a string representation of a symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9072/66) and the answer of rm -rf to [How to Print to the Console](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5734/66).

- The Print output using `$ShowIt = True` allows to use it in the front end if you change its style to Input.
- `$ReverseIt = True` allows to Print the result of Print in a reverse order as asked in this question.
- The Message if you switch it on using `On[Debug::ShowIt]` prints a *Mathematica* message and would stop the code if you used a message breakpoint in *Mathematica* or *Wolfram Workbench*.
- `$SowIt = True` allows to store what would be printed with Print in a symbol.

  To see the list of keys defined in the `debugSymbol` containing the results extracted from a program you can use the function [Keys](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/66).
- `$ConsoleIt = True` allows to output what would be output with Print but in the `Messages` console accessible in the menu `Window > Messages`.
- `$GroupIt` prints expressions in groups of two cells, for example `x` as title, and `x=2;` as expression.
- The `` System`* `` context of `ShowIt` and `ShowItList` allows to use them in the `` Private`* `` context of other packages without having to define the package in which these functions are defined (in `BeginPackage[]`, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7478/66) for more info on the organisation of packages).
- `ShowIt[]` is not shown inside another `ShowIt`.
- You can define a tag when calling `ShowIt`, and restrict which tags let `ShowIt` output things using `$ShowItTagPattern`.
- You can use `` Debug`ShowIt `` in parallel kernels (as `` System`ShowIt `` is recognised as a `` Global` symbol `` in a parallel kernel).

All in all `ShowIt` and the functions around it show a lot of different aspects of advanced evaluation in *Mathematica* that could be interesting to a lot of people.

```
(*Auxiliary functions*)
SetAttributes[ExtractSymbolName, HoldAll];
ExtractSymbolName[expr_] :=
Module[{T,SR = StringReplace[#, a__ ~~ "$" ~~ DigitCharacter .. :> a] &}, 
    Defer[expr] 
        //. HoldPattern[System`ShowIt@x_] :> x
        /. s_Symbol :> T@MakeExpression@SR@SymbolName@Unevaluated@s 
        /. T@_@x___ :> x
];

insertBelowEvaluationCell[expr_]:=
(
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,EvaluationCell];
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[expr],"Print"]]
);

$OldLine=-1;
SetAttributes[PrintToConsole,HoldFirst];
PrintToConsole[Defer[expr_],reversePrint_:False]:=PrintToConsole[expr,reversePrint];
PrintToConsole[expr_,reversePrint_:False]:=
 (
  If[$OldLine!=$Line,
        SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[],After,Notebook];

        NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[],
            Cell[
                BoxData@ToBoxes@"","Print",
                CellLabel->"During evaluation of In["<>ToString[$Line-1]<>"]:=",
                ShowCellLabel->True
            ]
        ];
    ];

    If[$OldLine==$Line,
        If[reversePrint,
            SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[],Previous,Cell];
            SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[],Before,Cell];
            ,
            SelectionMove[MessagesNotebook[], After, Cell];
        ]
    ];

    NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[],
        Cell[
            BoxData@ToBoxes@Defer@expr,"Print"
        ]
    ];

    $OldLine=$Line;
);

SetAttributes[PrintGroupedCells, HoldAll]
 PrintGroupedCells[label_, expr_] :=
Module[{tag = ToString@Unique[]},
    CellPrint[
        CellGroup[
            {
                ExpressionCell[label, "Item", CellTags -> tag]
                ,
                ExpressionCell[expr, "Input", CellTags -> tag]
            }
        ]
    ];

    NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], tag, All, CellTags];
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CellGroup"]];
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["OpenCloseGroup"]];
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell];
];  

(*Main function*)  
System`$ShowIt = True;  

System`$SowIt = False;  
System`$ConsoleIt = False;
System`$ReverseIt = False;  
System`$GroupIt = False;  
Off[System`Debug::ShowIt];  
System`$ShowItTagPattern = None;

System`Debug::ShowIt = "`1`";
SetAttributes[System`ShowIt, HoldAll];
System`ShowIt[expr_,tag_:None]:=
LetL[{evaluatedExpr = expr,exprWithSymbolNamesCorrected = ExtractSymbolName@expr,printedExpr = Replace[Defer[CompoundExpression[exprWithSymbolNamesCorrected = evaluatedExpr,Null]],Defer[x_]:>x,{3}]},
    If[MatchQ[tag,System`$ShowItTagPattern],
       Message[Debug::ShowIt,printedExpr];

       If[TrueQ@System`$ShowIt,
       If[TrueQ@System`$ReverseIt,
               insertBelowEvaluationCell[printedExpr];
               ,
                 If[TrueQ@System`$GroupIt,
                   PrintGroupedCells[exprWithSymbolNamesCorrected,printedExpr]
                   ,
                   Print[printedExpr];
               ];
           ];
       ];

       If[TrueQ@System`$ConsoleIt,
      PrintToConsole[printedExpr,TrueQ@System`$ReverseIt];
       ];

       If[TrueQ@System`$SowIt,
           Sow[
               evaluatedExpr
               ,
               Function[deferedExpr, ToString@Unevaluated@deferedExpr, HoldFirst] @@ exprWithSymbolNamesCorrected
           ];
       ];
    ];

    evaluatedExpr
]; 

SetSharedFunction[System`ShowItList];
SetAttributes[System`ShowItList, {HoldAll,Listable}];
System`ShowItList[expr_,tag_:None] := System`ShowIt[expr];

SetAttributes[ReapTags,HoldFirst];
ReapTags[expr_]:=
   Module[{elements},
      Reap[Check[expr,"failed"],_,(elements[#1]=If[Length@#2==1,First@#2,#2])&];
      elements
   ];

SetSharedFunction[Debug`ShowIt];
SetAttributes[Debug`ShowIt,HoldFirst];
Debug`ShowIt[x_]:=ShowIt[x];

SetSharedFunction[Debug`ShowItList];
SetAttributes[Debug`ShowItList,HoldFirst];
Debug`ShowItList[x_]:=ShowItList[x];
```

Example

```
(*Uncomment the line below to test a tag*)
(*$ShowItTagPattern = "tag";*)
$ShowIt=True; $SowIt = True; $ReverseIt=False; $ConsoleIt = True; On[Debug::ShowIt];
debugResult = ReapTags[x={1,2};y=3;z=4;ShowIt@Mean@x;ShowIt[z,"tag"];ShowItList@{x,y};];
debugResult["Mean[x]"]
debugResult["x"]
debugResult["y"]
debugResult["z"]
```

The argument of `ReapTags` can be any expression including the call to a function which is hard to split into simple pieces thus using `Reap[]` and `Sow[]` as underlying functions is useful in such a case.