# Printing grouped cells

Tags: front-end

How can I print grouped cells with CellPrint ?

The closest thing I have to what I want to do is this

```
CellPrint[CellGroup[{TextCell["i","Item"],ExpressionCell[Defer[x^2;],"Input"]},1]]
```

But the cells aren't grouped.

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
      CellPrint[
  CellGroup[{TextCell["i", "Item", CellTags -> "groupit"], 
    ExpressionCell[Defer[x^2;], "Input", CellTags -> "groupit"]}, 1]];
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "groupit", All, CellTags];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CellGroup"]];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell]
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be perfect if the grouped cells were closed, as the ExpressionCell typically contains big outputs in what I want to do.

Comment: I found it, FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["OpenCloseGroup"]]; before SelectionMove

Comment: Fyi I have incorporated your answer in my answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15134/66