# Refactoring: Why? When? How?

Tags: language-design

A good *Refactoring* can transform a kludgy WL code-base into a thing of pristine coherency but how to do so consistently?

Comment: Given its multiple programming paradigms and conintual influx of new constructs, the WL seems ideally placed to leverage Robert W. Floyd's following insight (yet there seems a general lack of explicit examples/codification for this process).

Comment: If the advancement of the general art of programming
requires the continuing invention and elaboration of
paradigms, advancement of the art of the individual
programmer requires that he expand his repertory of
paradigms. In my own experience of designing difficult
algorithms, I find a certain technique most helpful in
expanding my own capabilities. After solving a challenging problem, I solve it again from scratch, retracing only the insight of the earlier solution. I repeat this until the solution is as clear and direct as I can hope for ...

Comment: ... Then I look for a general rule for attacking similar problems,
that would have led me to approach the given problem
in the most efficient way the first time. Often, such a rule
is of permanent value. Robert W. Floyd.

Answer (score 3):

### Main activity

In functional programming languages refactoring is considered a main activity. Ideally we derive a new language that fits the problem we want to solve. (E.g. see the preface of ["On Lisp"](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) or the article ["The Roots of Lisp"](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/jmc.ps).)

This observation obviously does not help when we inherit code, or we have to adapt or re-design old code (because of changes in the language or our understanding).

### Big Ball of Mud

The article ["Big Ball of Mud"](http://www.laputan.org/mud/) gives well researched diagnoses and prescriptions of when and how to do refactoring. It is a good answer of the request:

> [...] transform a kludgy WL code-base into a thing of pristine coherency but
>   how to do so consistently?

Using that article, we identify how we ended up with the code we want to refactor, and then utilize the given prescriptions.

The article uses a [patterns language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). (Partially explained, I guess, that the authors are from the same university as one of the [Gang of Four](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GangOfFour).)

For MSE discussions that include using software design patterns in Mathematica / WL see these answers of ["General strategies to write big code in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109888/34008):

- Leonid's [preamble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109917/34008) to a large answer,
- [Object-Oriented Design Patterns application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109914/34008),
- [Design and programming DSLs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110129/34008).

I have used the patterns in "Big Ball of Mud" to refactor large scale air-pollution FORTRAN IV code (that was fairly large) into components of an object-oriented C++ framework.

Comment: Hell, if I can read and understand my own code 24 hours later, it's prefactored enough for me ;=} , and +1 for great references.

Comment: @ciao Thanks! Did you start programming education with Perl?

Comment: Actually, APL and Lisp were first languages, and with the former it really was the case if you understood it the next day you were writing legible code...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the handy overview and useful links. I wholeheartedly concur with the first two sentences of your answer but I also feel that learning how to put them into practice is perhaps not as readily met with the provided MSE links  as initially suggested or perhaps that it could be. Also, I would that argue that rather than "This observation obviously does not help when we inherit code, or we have to adapt or re-design old code (because of changes in the language or our understanding)" I would instead say that this observation does help and in fact ...

Comment: .. this is  what defines refactoring since "inheriting", "adapting", "redesigning" code is what needs to take place on an ongoing basis for any sufficiently large code-base. It's almost as if refactoring takes place at two levels, at a lower level in making code snippets more readable but at a higher level in designing the entire architecture. The first can perhaps be illustrated in a MSE answer but for the latter, I wonder if one has to see a poorly designed architecture transform into a cleaner one via refactoring - which for "big code" is admittedly hard to do in "small code".

Comment: @ciao I have not tried APL but I have ventured with J. So I understand the next day APL code readability test...